# Let $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$,then $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $A$ is dense in $B$, and $B$ is dense in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

The direction :

$A$ is dense in $B$, and $B$ is dense in $X$ $\implies$ $A$ is dense in $X$.

is trivial

But The direction that I am not capable of solving it completely is:

$A$ is dense in $X$ $\implies$ $A$ is dense in $B$, and $B$ is dense in $X$.

My try:

Assume $A$ is dense in $X$, then $Cl(A)=X$.

From given information, we have:

$A\subseteq B\subseteq X$

then

$(Cl(A)=X)\subseteq Cl(B)\subseteq X$

then

$Cl(B)=X$.

which means $B$ is dense in$X$.

But I failed to prove $A$ is dense in $B$.

Comment: What is the closure of $A$ in X, and what is the closure in $A$ in $B$? What does it mean to be dense in $B$, write the definition.

Comment: I mean$Cl(A)=B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $U$ be an open subset of $B$,then $U=B\cap U^{*}$,with  $U^{*}$ open in $X$,Since $A$ is dense in $X$,$A\cap U^{*}\neq \emptyset $, so $A\cap U \neq \emptyset$, which shows that $A$ is dense in $B$.The denisty of $B$ is easier, since open subset of $X$ meets $A$, it must meet $B$ (as $A\subset B)$.

Comment: Many thanks to you, for your help.